# Why this c code is not generating expected output?

Tags: c, visual-c++

I have written this simple c code in microsoft visual c++ 2010.

```
   #include<stdio.h>
    #include<conio.h>
    void main()
    {
    char title[20], artist[30];
    int numtrack, price;
    char type;

    printf("Enter the title of CD \n");
    scanf("%s",title);
    printf("\nName of the artist \n");
    scanf("%s",artist);
    printf("\nEnter the type of CD(enter a for album and s for single)\n");
    scanf("%c",&type);
    printf("\n Enter the number of tracks \n");
    scanf("%d", &numtrack);
    printf("\n Enter the price of the cd \n");
    scanf("%d", &price);
    printf("%s\n%s\n%c\n%d\n%d\n",title, artist, type, numtrack, price);
    getch();
    }
```

It's out put is

```
Enter the title of CD
ranjit

Name of the artist
mahanti

Enter the type of CD(enter a for album and s for single)

 Enter the number of tracks

4

 Enter the price of the cd
4
ranjit
mahanti


4
4
```

I can't understand why it is not waiting for input for type variable? Can anybody explain this please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of

```
scanf("%c",&type);
```

you want

```
scanf(" %c",&type);
```

Otherwise, one of the newline characters from the previous string is going to be consumed as the type.

Comment: This worked but can you explain me the logic please? when i removed the extra \n, why the problem did not solved?

Comment: The leading space on the scanf pattern string will cause scanf to consume all whitespace (spaces/returns/tabs/etc) before reading the character to be stored in `type`.  The `%s` pattern token will skip whitespace and read a string, then *stop* at whitespace (a newline) but **will not consume the whitespace**, leaving it in the input buffer.  You therefore need to skip this whitespace; the space before `%c` will do that.

Answer (score 0):

When you use scanf to read in a string, it reads in only a single word. This single word excludes the newline (`"\n"`) character. When you follow this by `scanf` to read a single character as you're doing with `type`, the newline character will be the character that's read.

You can fix this by adding a space before the `%c` which will ignore any whitespace (see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/): `scanf(" %c",&type)`

Comment: -1 This will fail miserably on OSes where the newline pattern is CRLF.

Comment: @cdhowie I was just busy editing that in :P @r.s.mahanti Try the update.

Comment: Why not just `scanf(" %c", &type)` as per my answer?  The leading space will cause scanf to consume all whitespace.

Comment: @cdhowie Ok, I wasn't aware of that but you're right so edited that in instead.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `getchar()` after `scanf("%s",artist);` so that the extra <kbd>`\n`</kbd> (or  <kbd>`\r\n`</kbd>) gets consumed.

Comment: What about OSes that use the "\r\n" pattern for newlines?

Comment: For OSes that use "\r\n", stdin will have already converted that to \n.

Answer (score 0):

The '\n' from the previous scanf is being processed for type